# What to do with a build "dist" folder

Tags: angular, build, publish, angular-cli

So I finished a very small angular2 project, and build it trough angular-cli with the command "ng build --prod".

I get a "dist" folder out of this. But what should I do with this dist folder in order to make it run ? Publish it to a server ?

Regards.

Comment: Yes, the dist (distribution) folder contains the bundled file that can be served by a web server, you can place the same in your nginx, apache, nodejs or any other static file server to be able to use the same in production

Comment: @Siddarth Sharma thanks !

Comment: So, how exactly do you place the dist folder to your webserver? Manually copy them?

Comment: @You can add them using FTP, or in my case we deploy them using dockers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! Upload the contents of the dist folder to your webserver to host it live. This step where you take your finished, built project and send it to the server is often called *"deployment".*

Depending on where you host your site you may have command line tools available to make deploying your app just as easy as building it (for example, upload to an Amazon S3 bucket with AWS command line tools, `firebase deploy` with firebase-tools, and even the Angular CLI can deploy to Github's gh-pages with `ng github-pages:deploy`)